# Create a script in Quickbase

Tags: quickbase

I'm not sure if it's possible or not but can you run a script in Quickbase? Such as in a formula field? If so, could someone show me a very simple example? I've figured out how to create custom Dashboards using jQuery so I assume we could do something similar on form/table.

Comment: Nathan mentioned Dan Diebolt's image onload technique in his answer but didn't have the link to his step by step guide to implementing it. The link: https://community.quickbase.com/quickbase/topics/how-do-i-setup-the-image-onload-technique-iol Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could try to accomplish this.  You can use Javascript in URL and Formula URL fields.  This will make the link button pop up a window that says "Hello World".

```
"javascript:alert(\"Hello World\");void(0);"
```

You can also load a page that you've created using Dan Diebolt's image onload technique.  I can't find his original post, but you use the onload event of an image tag to load a .js file.  In this example it's a page in the same application named `module.js` that is being loaded using a Formula Text field with HTML enabled.

```
"<img qbu=\"module\" src=\"/i/clear2x2.gif\" onload=\"javascript:if(typeof QBU=='undefined'){QBU={};$.getScript('" & URLRoot() & "db/" & Dbid() &  ?a=dbpage&pagename=module.js&rand='+Math.random())}\">"
```

The corresponding `module.js` file might look something like this:

```
(function(){
   alert("Hello World");
})();
```

You can take this as far as you'd like from writing functions in `module.js` that you call from Formula URL Fields to injecting your own HTML into the DOM (though Quickbase recommends you do not do that).  My favorite trick is to add `<span id="somethingUnique"></span>` either in the form builder or a text field with HTML enabled and use that to inject my custom buttons or data.